# Is $\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{5}$ rational or irrational?

Tags: arithmetic

Is $\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{5}$ rational or irrational?

One way is to let $x$=$\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{5}$ and then calculate $antilog \ (log (\sqrt 3) \times \sqrt(5))$ which gives irrational number.

But is there a way to check it without calculators..

Comment: It's not even algebraic.

Comment: I'm not sure why the form $10^{\frac{\log(3) \sqrt{5}}{2}}$ is any more likely to be irrational than what you've written. A computer can't tell you a number is irrational by direct computation (though a sophisticated program could work out the proof of some theorem.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a direct application of the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem). Interestingly, I don't think it's easier to prove that this number is irrational than to prove it is transcendental!